# What is the endpoint for Shopify Analytics API

Tags: c#, shopify

I'm looking at this [Shopify Analytics API](https://help.shopify.com/api/tutorials/analytics-api) documentation and they are showing how to query the SDK using [ShopifyQL](https://help.shopify.com/en/api/reference/analytics/shopify-ql), but I can't seem to figure out how to query it without an SDK. Is there an endpoint where one can submit an access token, store URI and ShopifyQL query?

Any ideas how to do that?

Comment: Take a look at the [Using Postman](https://help.shopify.com/api/tutorials/using-postman) section

Comment: That's useful, but it still doesn't tell me if there is an endpoint for Analytics API.

Answer (score 1):

the answer seems no. ShopifyQL can only be used within Analytics API which can only be used within apps using Embedded API SDK.
Might help to check within the SDK js file, though: https://cdn.shopify.com/s/assets/external/app.js

https://www.shopify.in/partners/blog/98577030-we-re-expanding-shopify-s-api-so-you-can-build-bigger-better

> "Shopify Apps can read aggregate data from Shopify to create
>   insightful reports and charts for merchants. Your apps can interact
>   with our analytics platform using ShopifyQL. "